# Python: Decorator for deferred function call

Tags: python

Disclaimer: I am fairly new to python (2 months)

I have a script which has to auto-generate a load of tests, and before doing its stuff, it needs to parse some data from config files. The thing is, some of this data can only be known later when all the config has been read, parsed, and processed. My current solution is to litter a file with functions of the form:

```
def Foo (arg1, arg2, ..., argn) :
    return lambda **kwargs : Foo_helper(arg1, arg2, ..., argn, refs = kwargs["refs"], vars = kwargs["vars"])

def Foo_helper(arg1, arg2, ..., argn, **kwargs) :
    ... some function statements ...
```

where I am priming with args 1 to n because the script doesn't know what functions it is calling. This is working but I hate having to define 2 functions in order to be able to call just 1. What I would like is something like:

```
@deferred
def Foo_helper(arg1, arg2, ..., argn, **kwargs) :
    ... some function statements ...
```

but my attempt so far of the form:

```
def arg_deferred(fns) :
    def newFn(*args, **kwargs) :
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return lambda **kwargs : newFn(*args, kw1 = kwargs["vars"], kw2 = kwargs["refs"], ..., kwn = kwargs["kwn"])
```

gets me ...

```
return lambda *args, **kwargs : newFn(*args, refs = kwargs["refs"], vars = kwargs["vars"]) 
KeyError: 'refs'
```

and this is happening at the point where I call Foo. I can't see why this is happening though because at the point where I call Foo I am only expecting to get a lambda back, which when called later will then call newFn, not to actually call newFn immediately. Am I doing something which for more experienced python users is obvious, is there a better way of getting what I want? (I have tried yielding instead of returning but didn't find a way to make that work either, and I've had a play with functools partial but I find myself calling the function with empty kwargs)

Comment: I don't quite understand the overall scheme of what your code is doing.  If you're generating the `Foo` function yourself, why don't you just put the `Foo_helper` code right inside it?  If you won't know it until after reading more config, why don't you just not attempt to write `Foo` until after you know everything you need to write it?

Comment: To make BrenBarn's point a little more clear, why don't you just call `Foo_helper` when you have all the arguments. It sounds like you're trying to provide some arguments now and then some more arguments later, it would be useful to know why you want to do this.

Comment: thanks for the clarifcation, the reason why I have to provide some arguments now, and then some later is that the only point at which I know *what* I want to call (and how) is in the config - but I don't want to call it at that point ... so effectively I need to bake them parameters there and then call it properly later. The script just blindly calls whatever function it is given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like maybe what you want is the [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) decorator. It does exactly what your `Foo` function does but in a more general way.

Based on your comment, you could also use a class to do what you want which might be a tad more pythonic:

```
class FooHelper(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, ..., argn):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        ...
        self.argn = argn

    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        # ... some function statements ...

foo_helper_inst = FooHelper(conf_arg1, conf_arg2, ..., conf_argn)
foo_helper_inst(refs = 10, vars = 2)
```

Actually, upon further reflection, the most pythonic way of doing this would be to create a class that represents your configuration that contains all the methods that you need. Something like:

```
class Config(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, ..., argn):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        ...
        self.argn = argn

    def foo_helper(self, **kwargs):
        # ... some function statements ...

    def foo_helper2(self, **kwargs):
        # ... some function statements 2 ...

    # ...

    def bar_helper(self, **kwargs):
        # ... some function statements ...

a = Config(conf_arg1, conf_arg2, ..., conf_argn)
a.foo_helper(refs = 10, vars = 2)
a.foo_helper2(foo = 1, baz = 2)
a.bar_helper(goo=3)
```

And you can pass these methods as callables:

```
def do_something(foo_func):
    foo_func(refs=10, vars=2)

do_something(a.foo_helper)
```

Comment: I've had a play with this module but so far I'm ending up with empty kwargs ... possibly I need to play a bit more :/

Comment: Hmm ... I find myself liking this class based approach the more I read it (so I write n classes as opposed to 2n defs) ... I'll give it a shot